# The method that will be called only within the class, still the method should be static?

Tags: static-methods

I understand the benefits of using the static method, invoking functionality without the instance of the class and hence saves memory.

But what about if the method will be called only within the class? still, is there any benefit using the static method?

```
Class Test {
    sayHelloWorld() {
        print "Hello" + getWorld()
    }


    // this method never will be called out side of the class
    // IDE say 'this method can be static'
    private getWorld() {
        return "world"
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. It can be private, but must be static. Static means you don't need an instance.

Comment: Both case, the usage will be same because, within the class, it doesn't create an instance within the class

Comment: But it's used from a non-static method so it must be on an instance. You could make both methods static, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern as a programmer in 2017 should not be about saving memory, but more about placing your abstractions in the right place. If you are using an Object-oriented language, using static methods is a smell of bad design IMHO. It allows C-style programming with global variables and functions, and make the code generally less testable.